# HP UFT Installer has IntelliJ plugin option unavailable

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, jetbrains-ide, hp-uft, leanft

I have installed JetBrains IntelliJ 2016.2.3 and am in the process of installing *HP UFT LeanFT runtime engine, SDK and IDE plugin*. I am supposed to get an option for IntelliJ since I have it installed already, but this option is unavailable. See screenshot.

[image: IntelliJ Unavailable]

Is there something that I can check or that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would like to give a try with silent installation? Save the below code as batch file and replace the appropriate folder and give a try.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET LEANFT_INSTALLER_LOCATION=C:\LeanFT
SET INTELLIJ_16_LOCATION=C:\IntelliJ16
SET INSTALLATION_LOGS_PATH=C:\LeanFTInstaller
::No visual indication of the installation progress
%LEANFT_INSTALLER_LOCATION%\setup.exe /s ADDLOCAL=LeanFT_Engine,LeanFT_Client,RegIntelliJ INTELLIJ_INSTALLDIRS=%INTELLIJ_16_LOCATION% /l*xv %INSTALLATION_LOGS_PATH%\LeanFTinstall.log
```

Reference: [Install LeanFT](http://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.54/HelpCenter/Content/Installation/LFTinst_install.htm)

Comment: Should I uninstall any existing UFT or LeanFT installations?

Comment: Please do an clean uninstall of existing LeanFT and give try.